# Add subtotal columns in pandas with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a 3-level deep multi-index on the columns.  I would like to compute subtotals across rows (`sum(axis=1)`) where I sum across one of the levels while preserving the others.  I think I know how to do this using the `level` keyword argument of `pd.DataFrame.sum`.  However, I'm having trouble thinking of how to incorporate the result of this sum back into the original table.

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

np.random.seed(0)

colors = ['red', 'green']
shapes = ['square', 'circle']
obsnum = range(5)

rows = list(product(colors, shapes, obsnum))
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(rows)
idx.names = ['color', 'shape', 'obsnum']

df = pd.DataFrame({'attr1': np.random.randn(len(rows)), 
                   'attr2': 100 * np.random.randn(len(rows))},
                  index=idx)

df.columns.names = ['attribute']

df = df.unstack(['color', 'shape'])
```

Gives a nice frame like so:

[image: Original frame]

Say I wanted to reduce the `shape` level.  I could run:

```
tots = df.sum(axis=1, level=['attribute', 'color'])
```

to get my totals like so:

[image: totals]

Once I have this, I'd like to tack it on to the original frame.  I think I can do this in a somewhat cumbersome way:

```
tots = df.sum(axis=1, level=['attribute', 'color'])
newcols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list((i[0], i[1], 'sum(shape)') for i in tots.columns))
tots.columns = newcols
bigframe = pd.concat([df, tots], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

[image: aggregated]

**Is there a more natural way to do this?**

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way without loops:

```
s = df.sum(axis=1, level=[0,1]).T
s["shape"] = "sum(shape)"
s.set_index("shape", append=True, inplace=True)
df.combine_first(s.T)
```

The trick is to use the transposed sum. So we can insert another column (i.e. row) with the name of the additional level, which we name exactly like the one we summed over. This column can be converted to a level in the index with `set_index`. Then we combine `df` with the transposed sum. If the summed level is not the last one you might need some level reordering.

Comment: I cant believe there isn't a simpler way of doing this in Python

Answer (score 1):

Here's my brute-force way of doing it.

After running your well written (thank you) sample code, I did this:

```
attributes = pd.unique(df.columns.get_level_values('attribute'))
colors = pd.unique(df.columns.get_level_values('color'))

for attr in attributes:
    for clr in colors:
        df[(attr, clr, 'sum')] = df.xs([attr, clr], level=['attribute', 'color'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)

df
```

Which gives me:

[image: big table]

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I'm mixed on this.  On the one hand, I feel like this reads more naturally than what I wrote. On the other hand, I always feel like I've come up a bit short when I need to use a `for` loop to get the job done in Pandas.  Which method do you think runs faster?

Comment: @DJ_8one6 I agree 100% on the uneasy feelings when using `for` loops with pandas objects. For that reason, I like your method more. I just thought this was too good of a question to not have any brainstorming going on :)

Comment: thanks for the encouragement.  I'm thinking about this sort of thing in the context of adding more useful marginals in pivot table type reports.  Basically sequentially reducing the levels in an axis and providing a subtotal for each level as you go.